# Error with materialize in Aurelia project

Tags: typescript, aurelia, materialize

Good day,

I have a .Net Core 2.1 project with Aurelia instaled. For the installation of materialize I followeed this:

https://aurelia-ui-toolkits-1.gitbook.io/materialize-bridge-docs/

But I have the problem that I can not use the select, apparently it is as if it was not initialized, I pass the information from the files

App.html

```
<template>
  <require from="materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"></require>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
   <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
   <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
</template>
```

App.ts

```
export class App {

  attached()
  {
     //Inicializar  los controles
     var element = document.querySelector("div.input-field select");
     M.FormSelect.init(element,{});
  }
}
```

Main.ts

```
import { PLATFORM, Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";
import environment from './environment';
import "materialize-css";

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
 aurelia.use
   .standardConfiguration()
   .feature('resources')
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"))
 .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-materialize-bridge'), b => b.useAll());

  aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
  }

  return aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Result on screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAiDL.jpg)

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Add the javascript file to index.ejs in the root of your project from `https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html` *OR* `import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'` and
`import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'`

Comment: I had imported the materialize in index.ts. M instance was active and import the js in the index.html, but it does not start the combo

Comment: Sorry, I just made a few mistakes with my current answer, I've updated it can you try it and see if it works for you.